# Как автоматически подбирать высоту строк в DataGridView под содержимое ячеек?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, resize

Имеется проект WinForms на .Net 5 с DataGridView. Мне необходимо программно изменять высоту строк в таблице (помимо этого установленные значения сохраняются в конфигурацию пользователя и применяются к DataGridView при загрузке формы). Для решения задачи значения свойств экземпляра DataGridView [AutoSizeRowsMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode?view=net-5.0) и [DefaultCellStyle](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle?view=net-5.0).[WrapMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode?view=net-5.0) программно меняются примерно так:

```cs
private void setWrapOn()
{
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
}
private void setWrapOff()
{
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.NotSet;
    dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    dataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
}
```

Не сказать, что это не имеет никакого эффекта:
[image: DataGridView AutoSizeRowsMode]

Как можно видеть работает только в одну сторону, т.е. если при загрузке формы был установлен перевод и автоподбор высоты строк, то отображается так, как необходимо. При отключении перевода строк и автоподбора - тоже всё работает, но не хочет в обратную сторону.
Пробовал обновить таблицу после установки значений так (в различных последовательностях и вариантах):

```cs
dataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
dataGridView.Invalidate();
dataGridView.Refresh();
dataGridView.Update();
dataGridView.Visible = false;
dataGridView.Visible = true;
```

Также пробовал унаследоваться от DataGridView для вызова защищённого метода [AutoResizeRow(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode, Boolean)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizerow?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_AutoResizeRow_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode_System_Boolean_), т.к. предполагал, что при передаче вторым параметром `true` новая высота будет рассчитываться исходя из текущей ширины столбцов.
Также пробовал обновлять привязку данных и тоже без эффекта.

Как программно включать и выключать автоматический подбор высоты строк в DataGridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету @AlexanderPetrov оформлю решение ответом. Путём <del>научного тыка</del> проб и ошибок было определено, что помимо установки [DefaultCellStyle](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle?view=net-5.0).[WrapMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode?view=net-5.0) нужно также установить значение для [RowsDefaultCellStyle](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsdefaultcellstyle?view=net-5.0).[WrapMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode?view=net-5.0) *(но и без DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode тоже будет работать)*:

```cs
private void setWrapOn()
{
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
}
private void setWrapOff()
{
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.NotSet;
    dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.NotSet;
    dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    dataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
}
```

Не смотря на то, что этот метод работает, был бы признателен знающим людям за разъясняющие комментарии по поводу такого поведения.